# how to turn off all vim settings for golang?

Tags: go, vim

How could I turn off syntax highlighting in vim, but only for Go?

I've seen a few posts about just turning off the red-highlighting for white space but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to your [vimrc](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#vimrc) file:

```
autocmd FileType go setlocal syntax=OFF
```

Comment: Thanks that was what i needed

Comment: You can also set `b:current_syntax` to prevent loading the file, or use `hi clear`. This has the advantage that you can stll add some syntax later on if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [the vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) states

> The syntax and highlighting commands for one language are normally stored in
>   a syntax file.
>   The name convention is: "`{name}.vim`".  Where `{name}` is the
>   name of the language, or an abbreviation

If you can find a `go.vim` file ([similar to this one](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/syntax/go.vim)) and delete it (or move it), that should disable the syntax highlighting just for Go.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to just prevent the file from loading. There's no need to move or remove any files.